# Hide div with js, but without affecting html code

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have a `div` with `id = '123'`

Ho to make it invisible with js without affecting its html code?
So `document.getElementById('123').style.display = 'none'` is not an option.

JS only

UPD:
 I just have interesting task! I have to hide some comments with js from guestbook , but when I change html code to hide it, Server somehow understands what I've done and redirects me to warning Page. So I have to do something with that.

UPD2:
I had obfuscated script on my page

```
function check_divs() {
var try_again = true;
var arr_divs = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('div');
if (arr_divs.length != divs_count) {
    try_again = false;
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_divs.length; i++) {
        if ((arr_divs[i].style.display == 'none') || (arr_divs[i].style.position == 'absolute')) {
            try_again = false;
        };
    };
}; if (try_again) {
    setTimeout(check_divs, 998);
} else {
    document.location.href = '/alert.html';
};
```

}

This one, so my solution was to clear all timeouts.

Comment: That's tricky! The reason something is visible or invisible is because of its HTML. The only option I can think of is to add a background-colored image to your page, then use javascript to make it the same size and position as the DIV so that the DIV is covered up by the image. :)

Comment: You can only make an element invisible by changing one of its CSS properties or removing it from the DOM altogether.

Comment: @user2950593 Probably because nobody understands what's that good for?

Comment: @dollarvar  I just have interesting task! I have to hide some comments with js  from guestbook but when I change html code to hide it, Server somehow understands what I've done and redirects me to warning Page. So I have to do something with that

Comment: @user2950593 Ask yourself: how could the server get to know about that? Do YOU send anything?

Comment: @dollarvar funny, I had obfuscated selfexecuted script which was sending get xhr requests after changing html.Is there a way to stop this xhr request if i don't know function which makes it?

Comment: If you have Chrome, go to Console, right click -> log XMLhttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('123').style.visibility = 'hidden';`

or

`document.getElementById('123').setAttribute('style','display:none');`

or

`document.getElementById('123').setAttribute('style','visibility:hidden');`

or if you have jQuery libraries

`$('#123').css('visibility','hidden')`

or

`$('#123').css('display','none')`

Any of that help?

Comment: And how actually does that not change the `html`?

Comment: The HTML is unaffected, and the structure of the DOM is 100% unchanged. You can revert this purely cosmetic change at any time.

Comment: wow - downvoted for what exactly? Answering the question 5 different ways? Or for explaining what it means to change HTML vs CSS?

Comment: Because you just gave him 5 versions for what he explicitly NOT wanted. lol

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wFE3e/) + see my Updated reason why i can't change HTML